# parse word from html file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I am having a lot of trouble trying to extract a word from an html file. The line in the html file appears like this:

```
<span id="result">WORD</span>
```

I am trying to get the WORD out but I can't figure it out. So far I've got:

```
 grep 'span id="result"' FILE
```

Which just gets me the line. I've also tried:

```
sed -n '/<span id="result">/,/<\/span>/p' FILE
```

which didn't work either. 
I know this is probably a very simple question, but I'm just beginning so I could really use some help.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regex to parse html.

Use a html parser.

My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) has the shortest syntax for this:

```
xidel FILE -e "#result"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for `awk` 
I do guess you have other line in same files so a search for `span id` is a must.

```
echo "<span id="result">WORD</span>" | awk -F"[<>]" '/span id/ {print $3}'
WORD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk -f ext.awk input.html
```

where `input.html` is your input html file, and `ext.awk` is

```
{
    line=line $0 RS
}

END {
    match (line,/<span id="result">([^<]*)<\/span>/,a)
    print a[1]
}
```

This will extract the contents across line breaks..

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with backward reference:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<span id="result">)\w+'
```

The expression between parenthèses is a backward reference; it is not captured but serves as test for the following regex part: if the expression appears, the captured pattern is only `\w+` here. Add option `-o` for outputting only the word; option `-P` enables forward and backward references.

If you want to modifiy this regex, please note that with `grep`, a backward reference must have a fixed size.